# Windows 7 Home Premium transparently cache Synology NAS

Tags: windows-7, nas, cache

How can I transparently cache a non-windows NAS on my Windows 7 home premium machines?  The same content tends to get retrieved over and over but I don't know which content it will be in advance.

Basically I am looking for a sort of Squid proxy but for home network files rather than HTTP.

Comment: I'd be curious if there are any solutions already out there.  If there are, they would take a pretty darn good programmer. The way Windows currently does this with another Windows box is do "change notifications" by looking at the USN journal on the NAS side.

Comment: @surfasb Could it not simply retrieve the file update date and re-fetch on that basis?  Most of the content it might retrieve is slowly or not changing (media).